# Таблица выходит за размеры контейнера на мобильном

Tags: html, css, table

На десктопе используя в CSS word-break: break-all удалось получить перенос слов в длинных строках и таблица в эмуляторе мобильника не выходит за пределы экрана по ширине. Однако на мобильном рисуется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки. Как ее убрать? Как поправить CSS, чтобы таблица не выходила за рамки контейнера? Страница товара, вкладка "характеристики" - https://4.sibgazkomplekt.ru/katalog/kotly/kentatsu-nastennye/kotel-nobby-balance-plus-12-2cs
Сайт на Opencart, но это не важно, видимо.

Уточню. На мобильном не срабатывает именно перенос слов. В результате ячейка не сжимается по ширине под ширину экрана и таблица отображается во всю свою ширину, с полосой прокрутки естественно. position : relative; - не дает эффекта

Comment: Покажите код со стилями

Comment: 1) чтобы убрать полосу прокрутки используйте в стиле overflow-x : hidden

Comment: 2) в dev tools вроде бы сработало, укажите таблице position : relative;

Comment: если не поможет то table .class { position: relative; width:100% !important; }

Comment: также можно убавить размер шрифта, чтобы она влазила или посчитать отношение размера шрифта к размеру экрана и сделать отноиельный размер

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Проблема была в теге , в который были завернуты строки в таблице.